# How to make dynamic template in ror...

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, html-email, spree

I am new to ROR.I am working on spree gem extension. I want to make email template dynamic means the content of html.erb file should store in database table .On shooting mail, all data and dynamic data are managed..?? Is it possible in ror and how to achieve this.??

Comment: It would greatly help if you could provide examples of what you need. What you can do is you have several templates of emails (for instance one for "items you liked", "items you might like", etc. or event "items you liked - female version"/"items you liked - male version"). So you can change the template of the email in your controller. Then, once the template is chosen you can use data from your databases as you would do in a normal view. So in your controller you get the data and you can pass it to the template.

Comment: "You have successfully placed Service Request No. #{@service_requests.id} for \#{@service_requests.category.name} . Our representative will be in touch with you soon for the same. Thank you."                                                                                                       This string is store in database. here @service_requests is dynamic object.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do like this just replace dynamic variables in DB like this:

You have successfully placed Service Request No. {service_requests_id} for {service_requests_category} . Our representative will be in touch with you soon for the same. Thank you." This string is store in database.

and create a helper

```
def replace_dynamic_variables(str,variables=nil)
    variables.each do |k ,v|
      str = str.gsub('{' + k.to_s + '}',v || "")
    end
    return str.html_safe
  end
```

and on mailer prepare variables like:

```
class yourMailer < ApplicationMailer

  def send_service_email(args) # email sending method
    @variables = {}
    # Other code like subject, to, from etc.
    @db_string = #string you get form DB
    @variables[:service_requests_id] = @service_requests.id
    @variables[:service_requests_category] = @service_requests.category.name
   #mail to: 

  end
end
```

and in send_service_email.html.erb/ send_service_email.txt.erb whatever suite in your case just call

```
<%= replace_dynamic_variables(@db_string,@variables)%>
```

I have not tested but hope this will work for you